# Flashing transparent glass textures in Eevee animation

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

I'm creating an Eevee animation and I'm having a problem where the transparent glass textures flash at various times and camera angles. I've tried adjusting a multitude of Eevee settings, but the flashing remains. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.3.1, Windows 11

[Video example](http://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/eevee_flashing_textures_example.mp4)

Edit: Also, I can't get the video link to work, so here it is again:

https://tinyurl.com/4nt5chd9

[image]

Comment: My only thought is it might have something to do with your _shadow mode_ (Under Blend Mode) for your transparent (glass) material - make sure it is set to "none".

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, no joy. The Shadow Mode was previously set to Alpha Hashed; changing it to None has no apparent effect. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you using any de-noising? That would be the next culprit, in my mind.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'm not using any denoising I'm aware of. I don't see a denoiser in the Eevee settings other than for the Viewport, and there's no post-processing. I tried an alternate Eevee glass material, but the result is the same. I'm going to keep tweaking other Eevee settings.

Comment: maybe share a part of your file?